# How to Reimplement System.out.print()

Tags: java, methods

just out of curiosity is it possible to make a method that prints the string in the parameter
I have no reason for doing this I just want to know what goes on behind the scenes of out.print and out.println

```
consoleString("Hello World!");    

public consoleString(string stringForConsole) {
    stringForConsole = What would go here to print this into the console?;

}
```

Comment: I doubt you'd accomplish it by assigning to stringForConsole.

Comment: If you want to know how the System.Out.Println works internally I think it is not a simple implementation, But you should know that it prints uses file and output stream, You can find excellent article for that [here](https://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/how-system-out-println-really-works/)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty basic question but

```
public consoleString(String stringForConsole) {
    System.out.println (stringForConsole);
}
```

If you use a IDE like Eclipse you can step into the code and see what it is doing.

If you click on `out` for example, you will see that it is using a PrintStream and uses

```
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println()
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(boolean)
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(char)
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(char[])
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(double)
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(float)
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(int)
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(long)
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(java.lang.Object)
 * @see     java.io.PrintStream#println(java.lang.String)
```

Comment: I think the person asking the question is asking for a way to implement System.out.print().

Comment: @Cppplus1 yeah maybe

Answer (score 1):

This is platform specific, but on linux systems (and other *nix systems), you could open `/dev/stdout` and write to it. Like,

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("/dev/stdout")));
ps.println("Hello, World");
```

Comment: @Cppplus1 Yes. That's what I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

**Q:**
What goes on behind the scenes of out.print and out.println

**A:**
This is a difficult question. I'm not sure but you can actually see the source code for `System.out.println(...)` and start tracing its code path from there.

The Java source code is available from the `JDK` package and it is available for grab on Oracle's Java download page found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

*--This is for Linux x64 package.--*

Unzip the package and you will see another nested zip package in there named `src.zip`. Unzip it for the source code.

**System.out code path**

Checkout the file `lang/System.java` file and you'll see the implementation for `println()`.

Just in case you're lazy to do the steps above. This is what it looks like.

```
public final class System {
    ...
    public final static PrintStream out = null;
    ...
}
```

So `System.out` is actually a `PrintStream` class. So now... you need to look at the PrintStream class...

Blah Blah and the story continues from `PrintStream` class.

You'll eventually come to this piece of code.

```
public void write(...) {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            ensureOpen();
            out.write(b);
            if ((b == '\n') && autoFlush)
                out.flush();
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

**Note.** This is not the end of the story... The code still goes on and on till you see output on the screen.